# How to set flexbox to fill the remaining height and be on the middle of the screen?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I'm trying to set the login container on the remaining height in the middle of the screen, it seems `justify-content` sets the content in the center, however, `align-items: center` doesn't work in this case, even if I set the container `height to 100%`.

I've tried also setting height 100% for the body, but if you resize the window it overflows somehow over the navbar and also in fullscreen you can scroll a bit which i don't want that.

I'm using tailwindcss. I've tried to replicate that also in custom css, but it doesn't work.

How can I fix this? I just want something simillar like when you go to google to login.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</head>
<body class="antialiased text-slate-400 bg-slate-900">
  <div class="h-full">
    <!-- Navbar -->
      <nav
        class="w-full flex justify-between items-center px-10 py-4 border-b border-b-slate-700">
        <a href="/" class="relative text-3xl text-slate-200 font-bold tracking-wider" >Navbar</a>
        <ul class="flex gap-5 cursor-pointer">
            <li>
                <a href="/" class="px-4 py-2 border border-transparent font-semibold rounded-lg duration-100"  >Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/login" class="px-4 py-2 border border-transparent font-semibold rounded-lg duration-100">Login</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

      <!-- Login -->
      <div class="h-full flex justify-center items-center">
        <div class="w-[350px] flex flex-col justify-center items-center space-y-10 px-10 py-10 border border-slate-700/50 shadow-lg rounded-lg">
            <h3 class="mb-5 flex justify-center items-center text-2xl font-bold text-sky-500 cursor-default">Login</h3>
            <form class="flex flex-col justify-center gap-3">
                <label for="username" class="font-semibold">Username</label>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    name="username"
                    id="username"
                    class="outline-none bg-sky-600/10 px-4 py-2 rounded-md font-semibold text-slate-300 placeholder:text-sm placeholder:font-semibold"
                    placeholder="Enter your username"
                />
                <label for="password" class="font-semibold">Password</label>
                <input
                    type="password"
                    name="password"
                    id="password"
                    class="outline-none bg-sky-600/10 px-4 py-2 rounded-md font-semibold text-slate-300 placeholder:text-sm placeholder:font-semibold"
                    placeholder="Enter your password"
                />
                <div class="w-full flex flex-col justify-center items-center gap-5 mt-10">
                    <button class="w-full px-5 py-2 bg-sky-500 rounded-full font-semibold text-white hover:bg-sky-500/80 duration-300">Login</button>
                    <a href="/register" class="w-full px-5 py-2 bg-green-500 rounded-full font-semibold text-white text-center hover:bg-green-500/80 duration-300">Create an account</a >
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider:

- Applying `height: 100%` on the `<body>` via `h-full`, so that the immediate child `<div>` "gets" the height with its own `h-full`.
- Applying `display: flex; flex-direction: column` via `flex flex-col` on the immediate `<div>` child of the `<body>` to layout elements in a vertical layout.

After the above two changes made, you could either:

Apply `flex-grow: 1` via `grow` to the `<div>` immediately after the `<!-- Login -->` comment:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<body class="antialiased text-slate-400 bg-slate-900 h-full">
  <div class="h-full flex flex-col">
    <!-- Navbar -->
    <nav class="w-full flex justify-between items-center px-10 py-4 border-b border-b-slate-700">
      <a href="/" class="relative text-3xl text-slate-200 font-bold tracking-wider">Navbar</a>
      <ul class="flex gap-5 cursor-pointer">
        <li>
          <a href="/" class="px-4 py-2 border border-transparent font-semibold rounded-lg duration-100">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/login" class="px-4 py-2 border border-transparent font-semibold rounded-lg duration-100">Login</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <!-- Login -->
    <div class="grow flex justify-center items-center">
      <div class="w-[350px] flex flex-col justify-center items-center space-y-10 px-10 py-10 border border-slate-700/50 shadow-lg rounded-lg">
        <h3 class="mb-5 flex justify-center items-center text-2xl font-bold text-sky-500 cursor-default">Login</h3>
        <form class="flex flex-col justify-center gap-3">
          <label for="username" class="font-semibold">Username</label>
          <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="outline-none bg-sky-600/10 px-4 py-2 rounded-md font-semibold text-slate-300 placeholder:text-sm placeholder:font-semibold" placeholder="Enter your username" />
          <label for="password" class="font-semibold">Password</label>
          <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="outline-none bg-sky-600/10 px-4 py-2 rounded-md font-semibold text-slate-300 placeholder:text-sm placeholder:font-semibold" placeholder="Enter your password" />
          <div class="w-full flex flex-col justify-center items-center gap-5 mt-10">
            <button class="w-full px-5 py-2 bg-sky-500 rounded-full font-semibold text-white hover:bg-sky-500/80 duration-300">Login</button>
            <a href="/register" class="w-full px-5 py-2 bg-green-500 rounded-full font-semibold text-white text-center hover:bg-green-500/80 duration-300">Create an account</a >
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Or apply `margin-top: auto; margin-bottom: auto` via `my-auto` to the `<div>` immediately after the `<!-- Login -->` comment:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<body class="antialiased text-slate-400 bg-slate-900 h-full">
  <div class="h-full flex flex-col">
    <!-- Navbar -->
    <nav class="w-full flex justify-between items-center px-10 py-4 border-b border-b-slate-700">
      <a href="/" class="relative text-3xl text-slate-200 font-bold tracking-wider">Navbar</a>
      <ul class="flex gap-5 cursor-pointer">
        <li>
          <a href="/" class="px-4 py-2 border border-transparent font-semibold rounded-lg duration-100">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/login" class="px-4 py-2 border border-transparent font-semibold rounded-lg duration-100">Login</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <!-- Login -->
    <div class="my-auto flex justify-center items-center">
      <div class="w-[350px] flex flex-col justify-center items-center space-y-10 px-10 py-10 border border-slate-700/50 shadow-lg rounded-lg">
        <h3 class="mb-5 flex justify-center items-center text-2xl font-bold text-sky-500 cursor-default">Login</h3>
        <form class="flex flex-col justify-center gap-3">
          <label for="username" class="font-semibold">Username</label>
          <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="outline-none bg-sky-600/10 px-4 py-2 rounded-md font-semibold text-slate-300 placeholder:text-sm placeholder:font-semibold" placeholder="Enter your username" />
          <label for="password" class="font-semibold">Password</label>
          <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="outline-none bg-sky-600/10 px-4 py-2 rounded-md font-semibold text-slate-300 placeholder:text-sm placeholder:font-semibold" placeholder="Enter your password" />
          <div class="w-full flex flex-col justify-center items-center gap-5 mt-10">
            <button class="w-full px-5 py-2 bg-sky-500 rounded-full font-semibold text-white hover:bg-sky-500/80 duration-300">Login</button>
            <a href="/register" class="w-full px-5 py-2 bg-green-500 rounded-full font-semibold text-white text-center hover:bg-green-500/80 duration-300">Create an account</a >
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set the height of the parent not to `h-full` but to `h-screen`, so it takes up all the space on the screen (100vh). Then set a fixed height on the navbar (e.g. `h-20`, which is 5rem).

Add a div surrounding your login form and make the height the remaining space on the screen (100vh - 5rem). Make this div `flex` and set `overflow-y-auto` on it to make sure it adds a scrollbar when there is not enough space.

Also add `m-auto` to your login div, to center the login form vertical and horizontal.

[Example in tailwind play.](https://play.tailwindcss.com/lYhhEhDQcd)

```
<div class="h-screen text-slate-400 bg-slate-900">
    <!-- Navbar -->
      <nav
        class="h-20 w-full flex justify-between items-center px-10 py-4 border-b border-b-slate-700">
        <a href="/" class="relative text-3xl text-slate-200 font-bold tracking-wider" >Navbar</a>
        <ul class="flex gap-5 cursor-pointer">
            <li>
                <a href="/" class="px-4 py-2 border border-transparent font-semibold rounded-lg duration-100"  >Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/login" class="px-4 py-2 border border-transparent font-semibold rounded-lg duration-100">Login</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <!-- Container with scrollbar: -->
    <div class="h-[calc(100vh-5rem)] overflow-y-auto py-4 flex">
      <!-- Login -->
      <div class="flex justify-center items-center m-auto">
        <div class="w-[350px] flex flex-col justify-center items-center space-y-10 px-10 py-10 border border-slate-700/50 shadow-lg rounded-lg">
            <h3 class="mb-5 flex justify-center items-center text-2xl font-bold text-sky-500 cursor-default">Login</h3>
            <form class="flex flex-col justify-center gap-3">
                <label for="username" class="font-semibold">Username</label>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    name="username"
                    id="username"
                    class="outline-none bg-sky-600/10 px-4 py-2 rounded-md font-semibold text-slate-300 placeholder:text-sm placeholder:font-semibold"
                    placeholder="Enter your username"
                />
                <label for="password" class="font-semibold">Password</label>
                <input
                    type="password"
                    name="password"
                    id="password"
                    class="outline-none bg-sky-600/10 px-4 py-2 rounded-md font-semibold text-slate-300 placeholder:text-sm placeholder:font-semibold"
                    placeholder="Enter your password"
                />
                <div class="w-full flex flex-col justify-center items-center gap-5 mt-10">
                    <button class="w-full px-5 py-2 bg-sky-500 rounded-full font-semibold text-white hover:bg-sky-500/80 duration-300">Login</button>
                    <a href="/register" class="w-full px-5 py-2 bg-green-500 rounded-full font-semibold text-white text-center hover:bg-green-500/80 duration-300">Create an account</a >
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```